# Hive-How to join tables with OR clause in ON statement

Tags: join, hive, left-join, hiveql, coalesce

I've got the following problem. In my oracle db I have query as follows:

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on 
(t1.id_1= t2.id_1 or t1.id_2 = t2.id_2)
```

and it works perfectly.
Nowadays I need to re-write query on hive. I've seen that OR clause doesn't work in JOINS in hive (error warning : 'OR not supported in JOIN').
Is there any workaround for this except splitting query between two separate and union them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to union two joins, e.g.,

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on 
(t1.id_1= t2.id_1)
union all
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on 
(t1.id_2 = t2.id_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support non-equi joins. Common approach is to move join ON condition to the WHERE clause. In the worst case it will be the CROSS JOIN + WHERE filter, like this:

```
select * 
  from table1 t1
       cross join table2 t2
 where (t1.id_1= t2.id_1 or t1.id_2 = t2.id_2)
```

It may work slow because of rows multiplication by CROSS JOIN.

You can try to do two LEFT joins instead of CROSS and filter out cases when both conditions are false (like INNER JOIN in your query). This may perform faster than cross join because will not multiply all the rows. Also columns selected from second table can be calculated using NVL() or coalesce().

```
select t1.*, 
       nvl(t2.col1, t3.col1) as t2_col1, --take from t2, if NULL, take from t3
       ... calculate all other columns from second table in the same way 
  from table1 t1
       left join table2 t2 on t1.id_1= t2.id_1
       left join table2 t3 on t1.id_2 = t3.id_2
 where (t1.id_1= t2.id_1 OR t1.id_2 = t3.id_2) --Only joined records allowed likke in your INNER join
```

As you asked, no UNION is necessary.